“the largest strongly connected component (LSCC)” measure equivalent in igraph?
I am trying to replicate “the largest strongly connected component (LSCC)” measure which seems to be absent from the general network analysis R 'igraph' package codes. The best I could find was “largest_component” command from 'igraph' package, but this only gives me the list of bank names with no numbers I need. So I guess this is only sorting the firm names instead of giving me values I need like this red box (below) in the paper’s snapshot does.
How can I replicate this LSCC network analysis values using R program?

I tried to use the R codes like in this link
However, it did not give numerical values I need such as for degree, closeness, centrality, etc. types of network numerical values.
The code I tried is as follows (which does not give any numerical values I need). I am not saying "largest_component" is the only available approach here. I am simply saying I also tried this code because you wanted me to provide any code in my question although that wasn't giving me the answer:
> library(igraph)
> largest_component(data,mode = "strong")
IGRAPH cd5f7d1 DN-- 94 988 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c)
+ edges from cd5f7d1 (vertex names):
 [1] ABCB US Equity->COLB US Equity ABCB US Equity->FULT US Equity ABCB US Equity->GABC US Equity ABCB US Equity->INDB US Equity
 [5] ABCB US Equity->BOH US Equity  ABCB US Equity->HOPE US Equity ABCB US Equity->NTRS US Equity ABCB US Equity->ONB US Equity 
 [9] ABCB US Equity->PB US Equity   ABCB US Equity->RNST US Equity ABCB US Equity->STBA US Equity ABCB US Equity->SASR US Equity
[13] ABCB US Equity->SBCF US Equity ABCB US Equity->SBSI US Equity ABCB US Equity->TRMK US Equity ABCB US Equity->UBSI US Equity
[17] ABCB US Equity->WFC US Equity  ABCB US Equity->SRCE US Equity ABCB US Equity->FFBC US Equity ABCB US Equity->PFBC US Equity
[21] ABCB US Equity->CADE US Equity C US Equity   ->CFR US Equity  C US Equity   ->EEFT US Equity C US Equity   ->NBTB US Equity
[25] C US Equity   ->OCFC US Equity C US Equity   ->PNFP US Equity C US Equity   ->PB US Equity   C US Equity   ->STBA US Equity
[29] C US Equity   ->SASR US Equity C US Equity   ->SBSI US Equity C US Equity   ->WABC US Equity C US Equity   ->BANR US Equity
+ ... omitted several edges
> components(gD_12_2022,mode = "strong")

And the snippet of my data is as follows:
 Date        i               j
09/2005 ABCB US Equity  CHCO US Equity
09/2005 ABCB US Equity  CHCO US Equity
09/2005 ABCB US Equity  CHCO US Equity
09/2005 ABCB US Equity  COLB US Equity
09/2005 ABCB US Equity  COLB US Equity
09/2005 ABCB US Equity  COLB US Equity
09/2005 ABCB US Equity  FITB US Equity
09/2005 ABCB US Equity  FNB US Equity
09/2005 ABCB US Equity  HBAN US Equity
09/2005 ABCB US Equity  HBAN US Equity
09/2005 ABCB US Equity  BOH US Equity
09/2005 ABCB US Equity  BOH US Equity
09/2005 ABCB US Equity  BOH US Equity
09/2005 ABCB US Equity  MTB US Equity
09/2005 ABCB US Equity  PNFP US Equity
09/2005 ABCB US Equity  SYBT US Equity
09/2005 ABCB US Equity  SYBT US Equity
09/2005 ABCB US Equity  SYBT US Equity
09/2005 ABCB US Equity  SIVBQ US Equity
09/2005 ABCB US Equity  SIVBQ US Equity
09/2005 ABCB US Equity  SIVBQ US Equity
09/2005 ABCB US Equity  TRMK US Equity
09/2005 ABCB US Equity  WFC US Equity
09/2005 ABCB US Equity  ZION US Equity
09/2005 ABCB US Equity  ZION US Equity
09/2005 ABCB US Equity  ZION US Equity
09/2005 ABCB US Equity  BRKL US Equity
09/2005 ABCB US Equity  BRKL US Equity
09/2005 ABCB US Equity  BRKL US Equity
09/2005 ABCB US Equity  CFFN US Equity

For other network measures like degree, centrality, etc.,  as I already mentioned, I have no problem producing them as they work as below (showing a snippet of my outputs). It is only the LSCC that I don't find any suitable code to run or execute from R:
Firms           Date    Degree       Closeness  Betweenness Clustering  Eigenvector
ABCB.US.Equity  09_2005 0.494623656 0.540697674 0.00484853  0.391304348 0.128802216
CHCO.US.Equity  09_2005 0.784946237 0.540697674 0.009498633 0.386809269 0.496275598
COLB.US.Equity  09_2005 0.612903226 0.550295858 0.007786027 0.386243386 0.265205502
FITB.US.Equity  09_2005 0.838709677 0.611842105 0.015768372 0.374307863 0.257392456
FNB.US.Equity   09_2005 0.494623656 0.436619718 0.002341893 0.383333333 0.47983247
HBAN.US.Equity  09_2005 0.64516129  0.510989011 0.008919628 0.342245989 0.507258004
BOH.US.Equity   09_2005 0.462365591 0.502702703 0.003176559 0.418300654 0.230633224
MTB.US.Equity   09_2005 0.731182796 0.513812155 0.011603933 0.346031746 0.560058904
PNFP.US.Equity  09_2005 0.731182796 0.502702703 0.006913042 0.406722689 0.668115579
SYBT.US.Equity  09_2005 1.494623656 0.611842105 0.041680331 0.352685051 0.70931023


The code doesn't create a graph, I have created it with g<-graph_from_data_frame(data). Then, I don't understand the largest components problem, the graph is connected, it only has one component, components(g). As for the other measures, run degree(g) and see this RPubs post.

You just need the number of nodes in the largest connected component divided by the number of nodes in the whole graph, so length(V(largest_component(data, mode = "strong"))) / length(V(data)) will give you the LSCC, assuming data is your igraph object representing the network.

So, do you mean each bank's value should be the proportion of the total banks that can be reached from that node?

What I can gather from the paper you quote is vcount(largest_component(g, mode='strong')) / vcount(g). However, it seems to me that this is not what you are trying to ask for. We really need a precise mathematical definition of what you want. So far you only said, "it did not give numerical values I need such as for degree, closeness..."

The data snippet provided in the question only contains outgoing connections from a single bank, so isn't adequate to demonstrate a solution to the problem. Here is a reproducible toy example that should suffice:
library(igraph)

set.seed(1)

d <- replicate(2, sample(paste("Bank", LETTERS[1:10]), 10, TRUE)) |>
  as.data.frame()

d <- unique(d[d[[1]] != d[[2]], ])
data <- graph_from_data_frame(d)

plot(data)


From my reading of your methodology paper, LSCC is the proportion of other banks in the data set that can be reached from each bank, following only outgoing edges. We can find this is igraph using the function subcomponent. For example, to find all the banks we can reach from Bank B, we can do:
subcomponent(data, V(data)["Bank B"], "out")
#> + 5/9 vertices, named, from 4b4f304:
#> [1] Bank B Bank G Bank E Bank I Bank F

You can confirm that banks G, E, I and F are all reachable from bank B in the above example.
We are interested in obtaining the proportion of all the banks that bank B can reach (excluding itself). That would simply be the number of nodes in the subcomponent (minus bank B) divided by the total number of banks (minus bank B). In other words:
(length(subcomponent(data, V(data)["Bank B"], "out")) - 1) / (length(V(data)) - 1)
#> [1] 0.5

This number means that half of the other banks can be reached from bank B.
To get results for all the banks, we can use lapply:
result <- lapply(V(data), function(v) {
   (length(subcomponent(data, v, "out")) - 1) / (length(V(data)) - 1)
  })

result
#> $`Bank I`
#> [1] 0.125
#> 
#> $`Bank D`
#> [1] 0.125
#> 
#> $`Bank G`
#> [1] 0.375
#> 
#> $`Bank A`
#> [1] 0.375
#> 
#> $`Bank B`
#> [1] 0.5
#> 
#> $`Bank C`
#> [1] 0.25
#> 
#> $`Bank E`
#> [1] 0.125
#> 
#> $`Bank J`
#> [1] 0
#> 
#> $`Bank F`
#> [1] 0

And if you want this in a data frame, you can do:
result |>
  as.data.frame(check.names = FALSE) |>
  t() |>
  as.data.frame() |>
  tibble::rownames_to_column() |>
  setNames(c('Bank', "LSCC")) |>
  dplyr::arrange(Bank)
#>     Bank  LSCC
#> 1 Bank A 0.375
#> 2 Bank B 0.500
#> 3 Bank C 0.250
#> 4 Bank D 0.125
#> 5 Bank E 0.125
#> 6 Bank F 0.000
#> 7 Bank G 0.375
#> 8 Bank I 0.125
#> 9 Bank J 0.000


Thank you. Actually, I have arranged the bank data to go from bank i to j in one direction only for data arrangement purpose. If I wanted to show bank j also affects bank i, then I switch their position and put down again according to bank i to bank j position again. (e.g., if A --> B and A <--- B as well, I put down as A ---> B and B ---> A instead). First of all, is this acceptable? If not, whether and how do I put both directions within one data structure? Or is my data structure already ok?

Also, I wonder whether "largest_component" code can be mixed together with you suggestion as well(?) Probably it would be the way how to determine the so called largest component like bank B.

@Eric the methodology specifies directed edges, which means you probably need both A ---> B and B ---> A, or else make your graph undirected. In this context, a largest component refers to a connected group of banks - we cannot talk about bank B being the largest component (it belongs to the largest directed component). Logically, the largest component in your data with effectively undirected edges will contain several banks, which will all be equally well interconnected. The method I show above allows you to find the bank with the greatest connectivity (bank B)

For some reason, I find the results are all straight "1" across all banks all the time.

In simple terms, when bank A's stock return granger causes bank B's stock returns, I put as A -- > B. If it granger causes three times in one quarter, I put A --> B three times in a row. I never put as A <--- B put I put this as  B ---> A instead always. But despite of this clear directional nodes, it is strange that I always get 1s all the time in all situations.

@Eric that's presumably because you can reach any bank from any other bank. If all your flows are bidirectional, then it's likely that there are chains of connection you can follow from any bank to any other bank. Perhaps you only want the number of banks that each bank interacts with directly? This is very easy to count. If not that, then perhaps have a think about what exactly you are looking for - it seems you are struggling to define precisely what you want.

It is actually the former. If so, what shall I do if my output keeps getting ones all the time?

and if that is scaled by the number of banks again, I think that is what I need for the LSCC measure.

When I simply copy and paste the data into my excel sheet, count the number of times that each bank appears in the first column i (as i is where it goes out all the time), then I seem to get the numbers differently for each bank. Actually, column j does not seems to be helpful in this process as my data only shows "out" not "in" because data is originally put as i --> j only. (as if I need to show j --> i, I simply put back the data of bank i to bank j location again).

@Eric so you just want the number of banks each bank deals with directly divided by the total number of banks? Is that correct?

I think Python has such code for LSCC (or they may call it as SCC) while R does not seem to have one. Not sure whether this is something to refer to as well.

https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.strongly_connected_components.html

I mean the problem of your code is having no duplicates. I meant I might need duplicates as the same granger causalities from the same firm to another same firm might occur multiple times in the same quarter

Unless you see the full data, you may not understand what I am saying. Despite of this now I have put down more data showing more than one firms coming from bank i. But if you know how I can supply the rest of the data, please let me know.

@Eric the problem is that if all banks in your data set connect to all other banks in your data set, then the LSCC is 1. That's just what the data says, and there isn't anything to be done about it.

I think you misunderstand. When bank i does not connect to bank j, I did not include it in the dataset. But bank i can connect more than once to bank j in the same quarter. So it must differentiate with how many times bank i connects to bank j in the same quarter which can be more than once.

@Eric but the number of contacts each quarter has absolutely nothing to do with the LSCC as defined in the paper. You are quite right that I do not understand what you are trying to calculate; whatever it is, it is not the LSCC and you haven't told us what it is. In any case, your question has now been closed by other expert users, including one of the authors of igraph, because it is not clear what you are trying to calculate. Instead of adding to the comments, please post a new question that clearly specifies exactly what you are trying to calculate.

I already have other network measures. LSCC is only an extra one I was trying to insert along with other network measures I have. If LSCC isn't suitable in my current context, then maybe I simply don't include it. For instance, if these are banks only inside the single country, then probably calculating the LSCC maybe meaningless if they essentially have to be all connected if belonging to the top market shares. How do you think?

@Eric that would be my guess. If all the banks in your sample can and do transact with each other then the LSCC is 1 and you can either include that fact in your description or leave it out altogether, as taken for granted.

So that is why I instead decided to focus on the 'count' of the connections (including overlaps), not the unique connections. If so, the code I use is as follows only focusing on the outward direction column 2. Please see whether this will suffice my purpose as I seem to get reasonable outputs: for (i in 1:length(unique(data09_2005[,2]))){
LSCC1<-sum(data09_2005[,2]==unique(data09_2005[,2])[i])/length(unique(data09_2005[,2]))
LSCC09_2005<-rbind(LSCC09_2005,cbind("09_2005",unique(data09_2005[,2])[i],LSCC1))}

@Eric OK. It's very difficult to follow code given in comments. What you are calculating is certainly not the LSCC, so I wouldn't call it that. It seems to be a count of the number of transactions made by each bank, scaled by the number of banks. If that's a metric that makes sense to you then by all means use it. I can't really comment on what you want to include in your data summary.

To confirm, I am counting the number of outward directions from bank i to any banks including duplicates. (because the list of unique banks between bank i and j are always the same). Then each are divided by the number of banks (or I could do the total number of outward directions from bank i to any banks). Then this creates distinct values for each bank.

Then the paper above explains LSCC as "the proportion of banks that are connected to other banks by following directed edges on the network scaled by the to- tal number of banks in the network." If this is different from what I just explained just above this, then maybe LSCC isn't a good measure for my case I suppose.

With the data in Allan Cameron's answer, here are two functions that compute the LSCC.
library(igraph)

LSCC1 <- function(x) {
  d <- distances(x, mode = "out")
  rowSums(d > 0L & is.finite(d))/(length(V(x)) - 1L)
}

LSCC2 <- function(x) {
  paths <- lapply(V(x), \(v) all_shortest_paths(x, from = v, mode = "out"))
  sapply(paths, \(p) {
    sum(p[["nrgeo"]] > 0) - 1L
  })/(length(V(x)) - 1L)
}

LSCC1(data)
#> Bank I Bank D Bank G Bank A Bank B Bank C Bank E Bank J Bank F 
#>  0.125  0.125  0.375  0.375  0.500  0.250  0.125  0.000  0.000
LSCC2(data)
#> Bank I Bank D Bank G Bank A Bank B Bank C Bank E Bank J Bank F 
#>  0.125  0.125  0.375  0.375  0.500  0.250  0.125  0.000  0.000

Created on 2024-08-25 with reprex v2.1.0

Note
To output a data.frame, pipe to as.data.frame and then fix the column names. In the output below, the row names are the vertices' names.
LSCC1(data) |> as.data.frame()
#>        LSCC1(data)
#> Bank I       0.125
#> Bank D       0.125
#> Bank G       0.375
#> Bank A       0.375
#> Bank B       0.500
#> Bank C       0.250
#> Bank E       0.125
#> Bank J       0.000
#> Bank F       0.000

Created on 2024-08-25 with reprex v2.1.0

@Eric igraph has a function simplify that returns a graph with no duplicates. Its output is always a graph, even if the input is a multi-graph. data |> simplify() |> LSCC1(), for example.

I mean the problem of your code is having no duplicates. I meant I might need duplicates as the same granger causalities from the same firm to another same firm might occur multiple times in the same quarter.

When bank i does not connect to bank j, I did not include it in the dataset. But bank i can connect more than once to bank j in the same quarter. So it must differentiate with how many times bank i connects to bank j in the same quarter which can be more than once.
